# Using SailsJS as RESTFul Backend application

Tags: api, backend, sails.js

I'm using SailsJS only as a backend api application and  I'm wonderng how to disable grunt and SailsJS frontend completely as I only make RESTFul calls from my frontend which is based on Backbone and RequireJS.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Grunt for a SailsJS can be as simple as just removing the **Gruntfile.js** from the project folder.  You can then remove the **assets** and **tasks** folders as well.